# Changing color of QLabel text? Accessing and modifying members of .ui file? [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple `QDialog` that shows a `QLabel` in black text. I'd like for the `QLabel`'s text to turn red when I press the `a` key. I am using the designer to make the dialog. Here is my code:

**myDialog.h**

```
#include <QDialog>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class myDialog;
}

class myDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit myDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
  ~myDialog();

private:
  Ui::myDialog* ui;

protected:
  void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
};
```

**myDialog.cpp**

```
#include "myDialog.h"
#include "ui_myDialog.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>

myDialog::myDialog(QWidget* parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::myDialog)

{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

void myDialog::eventPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
  if (event->key()==Qt::Key_A){
    Ui_myDialog::label1->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QLabel{color: rgb(170, 0, 0);}"));
  } else {
    qDebug << "FAIL";
  }
}

myDialog::~myDialog()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**ui_mydialog.h**

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'about.ui'
** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.5.0
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_MYDIALOG_H
#define UI_MYDIALOG_H

...<snip>...

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_myDialog
{
public:
    QLabel *label1;

    void setupUi(QDialog *myDialog)
    {
        ...<snip>...
        label1 = new QLabel(myDialog);
        label1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label1"));
        label1->setGeometry(QRect(50, 333, 16, 20));
        label1->setFont(font);
        label1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        ...<snip>...

    } // setupUi

    ...<snip>...  

namespace Ui {
    class myDialog: public Ui_myDialog {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MYDIALOG_H
```

So, here's the issue. When I build the project, a file called `ui_mydialog.h` gets created and is generated in the build folder. This file even says it was auto-generated by the Qt User Interface Compiler. When I try to change the stylesheet of `label1` (which is declared in `ui_mydialog.h`) in `myDialog.cpp` using the line:

`Ui_myDialog::label1->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QLabel{color: rgb(170, 0, 0);}"));`

...I get an error that says `error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Ui_myDialog::label1'`. This is where I'm stuck. How would I go about correctly passing `label1` into the `void myDialog::eventPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)` member function and modifying it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the `Ui_myDialog::` part? Just use `label1->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QLabel{color: rgb(170, 0, 0);}"));`

Comment: Yep, tried that and I get an error saying that label1 was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Oh you use your ui different than what I do (composition instead of inheritance). In your case it should be: `ui->label1->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QLabel{color: rgb(170, 0, 0);}"));`

Comment: Ahh, that did it. Could you add that as an answer so I can mark as complete? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Ui_myDialog::` on a non-static member is incorrect. 
You need to replace

```
Ui_myDialog::label1->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QLabel{color: rgb(170, 0, 0);}"));
```

with

```
ui->label1->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QLabel{color: rgb(170, 0, 0);}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `new Ui::myDialog` in 'myDialog.cpp'.

1) myDialog.h

Add `#include "ui_mydialog.h"`
Change `Ui::myDialog* ui;` to `Ui::myDialog ui;`

2) myDialog.cpp

Remove `ui(new Ui::myDialog)` in constructor.

And, then you can use `ui.label1->.....`.